# Need regular expression with dynamic values

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a regular expression which matches the dynamic values below coming from back end.

```
int passwordMaxLength = 10;
int passwordMinAlpha = 1;
int passwordMinCharType = 1;
int passwordMinLength = 5;
int passwordMinLower = 1;
int passwordMinNumeric = 1;
int passwordMinSpecial = 1;
int passwordMinUpper = 1;
String passwordNumberCharacters = "123";
String passwordSpecialCharacters = "@";
String passwordUpperCharacters = "ABC";
```

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have so far:

```
String pattern1 = "^(?=(.*["+passwordUpperCharacters+"]){"+passwordMinUpper+",})(?=(.*[a-z]){"+passwordMinLower+",})(?=(.*["+passwordSpecialCharacters+"]){"+passwordMinSpecial+",})(?=(.*["+passwordNumberCharacters+"]){"+passwordMinNumeric+",})(*["+passwordUpperCharacters+""+passwordNumberCharacters+"]*[@]){"+passwordMinLength+","+passwordMaxLength+"}$";
```

Comment: Basically, doing it as one regex is going to be a nightmare. I advice you to check all contraints one by one with a dedicated regex and ensure at the end that all contraints are respected

Answer (score 0):

As suggested a single regexp would be first difficult to make and second difficult to maintain.
Just imagine being new to a project and having to modify the regexp you provided ... honestly it would be a nightmare !

One good way of doing this would be to have a class that would check all of those constraints independently from one another.
You could imagine a method for each constraint. Then it would be really easy to understand while reading it, and under any constraint change you could do this as easily !

Here is an example of a class that could do it (for now just checking size and number of digits but it is easy to add validation)

```
public class PasswordChecker {

private int passwordMaxLength = 10;
private int passwordMinAlpha = 1;
private int passwordMinCharType = 1;
private int passwordMinLength = 5;
private int passwordMinLower = 1;
private int passwordMinNumeric = 1;
private int passwordMinSpecial = 1;
private int passwordMinUpper = 1;
private String passwordNumberCharacters = "123";
private String passwordSpecialCharacters = "@";
private String passwordUpperCharacters = "ABC";

public PasswordChecker() {
}

public boolean isValid(String password){
// here you can add many more functions !
    return hasValidLength(password) && hasValidNumberOfDigits(password);
}

private boolean hasValidLength(String password) {
    return password.length() <= passwordMaxLength;
}

private boolean hasValidNumberOfDigits(String password) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = password.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count >= passwordMinNumeric;
}
}
```

And then you could just call it using `passwordChecker.isValid(password)`

Then if you want to validate every statement and return a complete explanation of what is invalid in the password, I suggest you return an object having an boolean attribute for each wanted validation, then you return this object and it would carry for each validation if it is ok or KO like:

```
class PasswordValidation {

private String password;
private boolean hasMaximumLength;
private boolean hasMinimumNumberOfDigits;
// here add all of your validations ...
// also constructor and getters + setters
}
```

and in the `PasswordChecker` class you could add in your method something like this (example in the maximum length)

```
private PasswordValidator hasValidLength(String password, PasswordValidator validator) {
    validator.setHasMaximumLength(password.length() <= passwordMaxLength);
    return validator
}
```

and return this `validator` :

```
public boolean isValid(String password){
    PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator(password);
    validator = hasValidLength(password, validator);
    validator = hasValidNumberOfDigits(password, validator);

    // here keep validating
    return validator;

}
```